# How to modify every nth item in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, append

I am trying to find the most efficient way to get every fifth item in an array and then modify it with a str_replace.

For example to modify the [3r] to [4r] only every fifth item.

> $myArray = array("apples[3r]", "jacobs[3r]", "chocolate[3r]", "makeup[3r]", "lipstick[3r]", "triangle[3r]", "jacobson[3r]", "lacksasf[3r]","dahe[3r]", "applestoapples[3r]", "coaxale[3r]", "hamburger[3r]", "prefix[3r]"

And this to output

> apples[3r] jacobs[3r] chocolate[3r] makeup[3r] lipstick[4r] triangle[3r] jacobson[3r] lacksasf[3r] dahe[3r] applestoapples[4r] coaxale[3r] hamburger[3r] prefix[3r]

Comment: No need to add the tag to the start of your title. This is not a '90s message board. Please look at high-voted existing questions for inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a "for" **starting from 4** (the 5th element of your array) and increasing 5 every step:

```
for ($i = 4; $i < count($myArray); $i += 5) {
    $myArray[$i] = str_replace('[3r]', '[4r]', $myArray[$i]);
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to assign the result to the array again.

Comment: +1 - the most elegant solution, I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 0; $i*5+4 < sizeof($myArray); $i++) {
    $myArray[$i*5+4] = str_replace("[3r]","[4r]", $myArray[$i*5+4]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( $i=0;$i<count( $array );$i+=<N-1> ){
   ...
}
```

use a for loop and add N-1 every time

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = array("apples[3r]", "jacobs[3r]", "chocolate[3r]", "makeup[3r]", "lipstick[3r]", "triangle[3r]", "jacobson[3r]", "lacksasf[3r]","dahe[3r]", "applestoapples[3r]", "coaxale[3r]", "hamburger[3r]", "prefix[3r]");

$len = count($myArray);
$total = floor($len/5);
$count = 5;
for($i=0, $i<= $total, $i++) {
    $myArray[$count] = str_replace("[3r]", "[4r]", $myArray[$count]);
    $count += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over you array but only change every fith item:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($myArray as &$value)
{
    if ($i++ % 5) continue;   
    $value = str_replace(/* lookup the manual if you don't know this function */);
}
unset($value);
```

If you don't want to start counting at `0` initialize `$i` with `-4`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do this change:

```
$myArray = array(
  "apples[3r]", 
  "jacobs[3r]", 
  "chocolate[3r]", 
  "makeup[3r]", 
  "lipstick[3r]", 
  "triangle[3r]", 
  "jacobson[3r]", 
  "lacksasf[3r]",
  "dahe[3r]", 
  "applestoapples[3r]", 
  "coaxale[3r]", 
  "hamburger[3r]", 
  "prefix[3r]"
);

$sizeMyArray = count($myArray);

for ($i = 4; $i < $sizeMyArray; $i+= 5) {
  $myArray[$i] = str_replace('[3r]', '[4r]', $myArray[$i]);
}

print_r($myArray);

/* Array ( 
 * [0] => apples[3r] 
 * [1] => jacobs[3r] 
 * [2] => chocolate[3r] 
 * [3] => makeup[3r] 
 * [4] => lipstick[4r] 
 * [5] => triangle[3r] 
 * [6] => jacobson[3r] 
 * [7] => lacksasf[3r] 
 * [8] => dahe[3r] 
 * [9] => applestoapples[4r] 
 * [10] => coaxale[3r] 
 * [11] => hamburger[3r] 
 * [12] => prefix[3r] ) */
```